How to remove the User Name Field from the identity user in asp.net core 8
I want to remove the UserName field from the IdentityUser
I don't want to use it

You need to create a class that inherits from IdentityUser
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public override string UserName
    {
        get => null;
        set {}
    }
}

Register it like
builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
{
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
})

It will work.
The only thing you need is to manually drop the column from the database, or modify the DBContext like
builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
         .Ignore(u => u.UserName);

Hope it helps
